# Recursion crashing Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I have this javascript / jquery function:

```
  function press_quotes_slider(ele) {
    jQuery.fn.exists = function(){return this.length>0;}
    if ($j(ele).next().exists()) {
        var ele_next = $j(ele).next();
    } else {
        var ele_next = $j('#press_quotes').children().first();
    }

    ele.fadeOut(4000);
    ele_next.fadeIn(4000);

    press_quotes_slider (ele_next);
  }
```

I'm having a problem with this crashing Chrome.
If I disable the recursive aspect of this function, it runs fine so this doesn't appear to be a syntex error.

Can anyone suggest a way round this?

Comment: Infinite recursion? You need to stop calling `press_quotes_slider` at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Callback -

```
ele_next.fadeIn(4000,function(){
     press_quotes_slider (ele_next);
});
```